# Let A and B be two sets of sequences. I want to say whether or not they are orthonormal basis for $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let A and B be two sets of sequences. I want to say whether or not they are orthonormal basis for $l^2$. More specific:

A = { (1,2,0,0,0,0...), (0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,..), (0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,..) }

B = { (1,-1,0,0,0,0,...), (1,1,0,0,0,0,...), (0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0), (0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)}

Now, I know that a set is said to be orthonormal basis of H if it is an orthonormal set and it is complete. Both A and B are orthonormal, but I am struggling to see if they are complete. To disprove this fact I would need to find a sequence in $l^2$ such that it is not made by elements of A, but I am also struggling to see how to prove this statement in positive.

EDIT: For A), I think that (1,0,0,0,0,0...) is in $l^2$ but cannot be made by elements in A, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(-2,1,0,0,0,\cdots)$ is orthogonal to everything in $A$. So $A$ is not an orthogonal basis.

The second set is an orthogonal basis; all the standard basis elements can be written in terms of these elements, and they are mutually orthogonal.